# Enabling Hyper-V for VS 2019 Xamarin debugging

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, hyper-v

I'm running VS Community 2019 16.7.2 on Windows 10 Pro, 2004, 19041.150
I'm on an AMD Ryzen 5 3600 w/ 16 Gb RAM in 64bit mode.

At the command line, running `systeminfo` I get:
`Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.`

When I'm in my Xamarin project, I see:
'You can get a greatly improved Android Emulator experience by enabling Hyper-V.`

I thought I DID enable Hyper-V. Read through some documentation, but couldn't figure out what I was missing.

Comment: Read  the document about [Enabling Hyper-V acceleration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows#accelerating-with-hyper-v) would help. There are detailed steps.

Comment: Did you enable Windows Hypervisor Platform:?

Comment: I did all the steps in the linked article, and VS 2019 still reminds me on boot. Sometimes I even get multiple copies of the same alert bar.  I'm cool with "Don't show again", but it feels like it should only show if I'm missing something ... ?